# Calculating bytes needed to store a string using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using `BinaryWriter` to write a string to a file. For unrelated reasons I need to calculate how many bytes this will require but I'm seeing results that don't match the documentation.

With this test code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) {
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
        writer.Write("Test");
    }
}
```

I expect the file to be 8 bytes:

- Using `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str)` (UTF-8 is the default used by BinaryWriter), it reports the string `Test` is 4 bytes.
- [According to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx), BinaryWriter prefixes the output string with an "unsigned integer" which is 4 bytes.

However, the written file is only 5 bytes, and all of my file offset math works when I assume strings are always `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str) + 1` bytes.

I'm not clear on where the difference is.

This is being tested in Unity 5.6, which uses Mono / .NET 2.0 and some Mono / .NET 3.5.

Comment: You may also want to check how integers are written (compact format similar to UTF8) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, that may be it. "If value will fit in seven bits, it takes only one byte of space". That's going to complicate my math for determining offsets. I sure wish there was an easier way to calculate how much room BinaryWriter will use without having to replicate the logic.

Comment: You can always write once and just collect size info... Or just override writing string and write the way you like (you'd have to match read too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that documentation says it writes size uncompressed. It is very wasteful and I expect compressed format for length provided by [BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint(v=vs.110).aspx) which indeed requires 1 byte for integer below 127.

[Reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,166b0572d9c907b3,references) confirms that expectation:

```
 public unsafe virtual void Write(String value) 
 {
     ... 
     int len = _encoding.GetByteCount(value);
     Write7BitEncodedInt(len);
```

Comment: I didn't even consider the int would be written differently, so good catch. One followup, what's the best way for me to calculate the true bytes needed? `sizeof` doesn't take into account this method of writing. Is there something that does?

Comment: I don't think so. I'd copy Write7BitEncodedInt and modify it to just count bytes.

Comment: Simple enough, that's what I've done. Any idea why this 7Bit encoding is only used for the string length int? Why not any int32?

Comment: My guess is strings are usually short enough so cost of extra 3 bytes is easily noticeable (like list of words would have  about 25% wasted on extra bytes for length) while all other usages are less clear cut. If you know that your integers are small enough you can write them with Write7BitEncodedInt too.